# Getting memory / driver related BSOD while memory is supposedly intact

Tags: windows, memory, drivers, bsod

Good day everyone,
I finally decided to search for some help on here after struggling with blue screens multiple times a day for almost half a year now. The blue screens codes I come across are:

- "HYPERVISOR_ERROR",
- "DRIVER_IQRL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL"
- and newly "ATTEMPTED_EXECUTE_OF_NOEXECUTE_MEMORY".

They must be hardware related for the following reasons:

1. The errors do not occure when at a different pc with the same system / drives
2. I've reinstalled windows last friday
3. I doubt that lenovo has their drivers corrupted for half a year

As far as I could see the dump files always point to a different program for the cause. A memory diagnosis by lenovo showed now problems, neither for my gpu or cpu. I didn't have the time to run a full memory diagnosis using windows yet.

I can provide dump files on request. However, I do not have saved them until now. Therefor I might only be able to provide mini dumps or once an error occures again (which shouldn't take too long.

Also my pc sometimes crashes without any error. The system event points towards a problem with the powersupply. However, my pc has been at lenovos repair shop last week for a problem with my mainboard.

Edit: The dump of a one DRIVER_IQRL_... BSOD

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000178, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000001, bitfield :
    bit 0 : value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
    bit 3 : value 0 = not an execute operation, 1 = execute operation (only on chips which support this level of status)
Arg4: fffff80116220651, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 4874

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 7723

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 530

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 11734

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 243

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: ni_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2022-05-06T12:50:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.22621.1


FILE_IN_CAB:  MEMORY - Kopie.DMP

TAG_NOT_DEFINED_202b:  *** Unknown TAG in analysis list 202b


DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0x1800

BUGCHECK_CODE:  a

BUGCHECK_P1: 178

BUGCHECK_P2: 2

BUGCHECK_P3: 1

BUGCHECK_P4: fffff80116220651

WRITE_ADDRESS:  0000000000000178 

PROCESS_NAME:  waterfox.exe

TRAP_FRAME:  fffff582674e6490 -- (.trap 0xfffff582674e6490)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff80116220651 rsp=fffff582674e6620 rbp=000f807fb8bbbdff
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=00000000000000f6 r10=00009e110060d0f6
r11=0000000000000000 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
nt!SwapContext+0x421:
fffff801`16220651 22e0            and     ah,al
Resetting default scope

MISALIGNED_IP: 
nt!SwapContext+421
fffff801`16220651 22e0            and     ah,al

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff582`674e6348 fffff801`1622c4e9     : 00000000`0000000a 00000000`00000178 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000001 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff582`674e6350 fffff801`16227a34     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
fffff582`674e6490 fffff801`16220651     : ffffe30d`3208d0c0 fffff801`160ecb00 00000000`00400000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiPageFault+0x474
fffff582`674e6620 00009e11`0060d0f6     : 00000000`00000048 00000000`00000004 00000000`00000028 fffff801`160d4c9a : nt!SwapContext+0x421
fffff582`674e6660 00000000`00000048     : 00000000`00000004 00000000`00000028 fffff801`160d4c9a ffffe30d`20744040 : 0x00009e11`0060d0f6
fffff582`674e6668 00000000`00000004     : 00000000`00000028 fffff801`160d4c9a ffffe30d`20744040 ffffc581`80cd1180 : 0x48
fffff582`674e6670 00000000`00000028     : fffff801`160d4c9a ffffe30d`20744040 ffffc581`80cd1180 ffffc581`80cd1180 : 0x4
fffff582`674e6678 fffff801`160d4c9a     : ffffe30d`20744040 ffffc581`80cd1180 ffffc581`80cd1180 ffffe30d`3a7c2080 : 0x28
fffff582`674e6680 fffff801`162203f7     : ffffe30d`3208d0c0 ffffe30d`3a7c2990 00000000`00000000 ffffc581`80cd1180 : nt!KiBeginThreadAccountingPeriod+0x11a
fffff582`674e66c0 fffff801`162201c6     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!SwapContext+0x1c7
fffff582`674e6700 fffff801`1606c9d5     : 00000000`00000020 00000000`00000000 000f807f`b8bbbdff ffffe30d`2eb81080 : nt!KiSwapContext+0x76
fffff582`674e6840 fffff801`1606ebb7     : ffffe30d`3a7c2080 00000000`00000000 0000089b`00000001 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSwapThread+0xab5
fffff582`674e6990 fffff801`1600d83b     : ffffe30d`00000000 ffffe30d`00000001 fffff582`0000006a 00000001`b1aa88e6 : nt!KiCommitThreadWait+0x137
fffff582`674e6a40 fffff801`164a7300     : ffffe30d`3a7c2080 fffff582`674e6b60 fffff582`674e6b60 00000182`00000002 : nt!KeWaitForAlertByThreadId+0xd7
fffff582`674e6ab0 fffff801`1622bbe8     : ffffe30d`3a7c2080 fffff582`674e6af0 ffffffff`fffdb610 00000000`00000000 : nt!NtWaitForAlertByThreadId+0x30
fffff582`674e6ae0 00007fff`07452f64     : 00007fff`074191eb 40f0c638`00000000 0000069d`ff533fb0 00000182`14fac280 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x28
0000004d`0647eb88 00007fff`074191eb     : 40f0c638`00000000 0000069d`ff533fb0 00000182`14fac280 0000004d`0647ec08 : ntdll!NtWaitForAlertByThreadId+0x14
0000004d`0647eb90 00007fff`04c52e49     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000182`14f5b450 00007ffe`aa6e8fd7 : ntdll!RtlSleepConditionVariableSRW+0x13b
0000004d`0647ec10 00007ffe`aa6d113a     : 00000182`14f5b450 000056b8`a042bb20 00000000`00000000 00000182`14f5b450 : KERNELBASE!SleepConditionVariableSRW+0x29
0000004d`0647ec50 00007ffe`9c84f881     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000182`14fac118 00000182`14f5b450 : mozglue!mozilla::detail::ConditionVariableImpl::wait_for+0x8a
0000004d`0647ec80 00007ffe`9d9296cd     : ffffffff`00000000 00007fff`04c0f70c 00007fff`073d851d 00000000`00000000 : xul!XRE_GetBootstrap+0x7ed611
0000004d`0647f2d0 00007ffe`9d928801     : 00000000`00000030 00007ffe`a3cdd4a8 00000182`14f3bd00 0000004d`0647f860 : xul!GIFFT_TimingDistributionCancel+0x5c622d
0000004d`0647f660 00007ffe`9c9f4bff     : 00000000`00000005 00000182`14f5cda0 0000004d`0647f7e0 00007ffe`a3cdd4a8 : xul!GIFFT_TimingDistributionCancel+0x5c5361
0000004d`0647f710 00007ffe`9c07bc8e     : 00000000`00000000 0002ffff`00001f80 00000182`14f04608 000056b8`a042a7f0 : xul!XRE_GetBootstrap+0x99298f
0000004d`0647f760 00007ffe`9c850da8     : 00002d18`398848b3 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00007fff`04c1f6fe : xul!XRE_GetBootstrap+0x19a1e
0000004d`0647f7c0 00007ffe`a3b2682d     : 00000182`14c447a0 00000182`17df3100 00000182`17df3238 00000182`17df3100 : xul!XRE_GetBootstrap+0x7eeb38
0000004d`0647f970 00007ffe`a3b38461     : 00000000`00000000 00000182`14c4a500 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nss3!PR_ParseTimeString+0x26d
0000004d`0647f9e0 00007fff`04ae9363     : 00000182`14c447a0 00000182`14c447a0 00000000`00000000 00007fff`04c4e899 : nss3!PR_MD_INIT_LOCKS+0x71
0000004d`0647fa10 00007fff`0619257d     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000030 0000004d`0647fa88 : ucrtbase!thread_start<unsigned int (__cdecl*)(void *),1>+0x93
0000004d`0647fa40 00007ffe`aa6d1ae8     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000182`14c447a0 00000000`00000030 : KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x1d
0000004d`0647fa70 00007fff`0740aa58     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : mozglue!mozilla::mscom::detail::EndProcessRuntimeInit+0x38
0000004d`0647fae0 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x28


SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!SwapContext+421

IMAGE_NAME:  hardware

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr; .ecxr ; kb

MODULE_NAME: hardware

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  IP_MISALIGNED

OS_VERSION:  10.0.22621.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  ni_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {201b0e5d-db2a-63d2-77be-8ce8ff234750}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Edit 2: Google drive with dumps, will be updated while collecting more files
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VvoKxgDLPelu7O1x5DUxhjGc3kTf2eVx?usp=sharing

Comment: Post the WinDBG analysis of the most relevant memory dump. Sounds like your problem is linked to the repair that was performed

Comment: The problem already existed before of the repair. One time a screw on my mainboard got loosed and caused a short circuit, but I don't remember if the problem started before or after that. I posted the dump of  DRIVER_IQRL_... in my post.

Comment: See if Reliability History shows errors in a helpful way to you. Control Panel, Security and Maintenance.

Comment: Nothing useful in there. They all either point to the dumps or just say that the device was shut down unexpectedly

Comment: Run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) for as many hours as you can, for example overnight. This will test more than just the RAM. Also post online some `.dbg` crashes for us to examine.

Comment: Try booting and running an OS from USB, such as WinToUSB or Linux, for a while. If that works without BSOD, likely the issue is in OS (despite reinstallation) or boot drive.

Comment: @harrymc where can I find the .dbg?

Comment: Sorry, I meant '.dmp'.

Comment: @harrymc okay, it alright. Do you need the file itself or is the output of windbg (like the one above) sufficient? Also I ran the test for 4 iterations (the max amount in the free version) and didn't have any errors

Comment: I need the file(s) itself, as of them many as possible.

Comment: @harrymc I added a google drive link where I'll upload the dumps, will take some time though as each file is 16GB in size

Comment: Zipping them can save space. Minidumps are OK.

Comment: @harrymc okay, that save a lot of trouble as my pc crashed again while trying to upload the first dump. I uploaded the minidumps in one zip now. Thank you

Comment: The crash is happening inside Windows, no driver seems to be involved. I suggest to verify the hardware by running [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) for many hours, even overnight, to test the RAM and the general CPU/bus functions.

Comment: @harrymc So I was right :/ I already ran memtest without any error found. Do you know if there is a way to test the integrity of the gpu (nvidia)? I have the feeling it might be the GPU as the crashes are more common when playing games

Comment: Everything is possible, but the display driver was not on the stack in any of the dumps, so I would say it's not likely the problem. General checkup: Check the Event Viewer for interesting errors, run `chkdsk`, verify the SMART attributes of the disk, test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). Note that MemTest86 needs many hours for an exhaustive test.